# Boliviana de Aviacion (BOA) tariff codes

Tags: online-resources, airlines, terminology, bolivia, boa

I am trying to book one-way tickets on BOA on Jan 13 2015 from La Paz (LBP) to Buenos Aires (EZE) from their website.

Their website asks me to make a choice between 7(!) different tariff codes - they are SSEEOB, QEEOB, TMEEOB, VEEOB, HEEOB, BEEOB, YOW. The prices are different for every tariff, but other than that I cannot see any obvious difference and there is no explanation available. Also I am unable to find anything useful on their website

Could anyone from Bolivia or familiar with BOA explain what is going on there and what choice am I supposed to make?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You dont seem to have many warm feelings about them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to contact them through their Facebook page.

They say:

```
the provided service and checked baggage is the same, no matter which 
the fare is, as we mentioned earlier, the only difference between fares 
is the percentage of discount in the fare.
```

So it seems to be "pick your own discount" type of thing. It really is puzzling to me as to why would anyone pick anything other than the lowest possible price, but apparently offering this kind of choice makes sense to somebody out there.

**Update 2015-10-01:** Have had 2 flights with BoA now and the cheapest fare worked out fine, luggage (up to 23kg) was included, no other difference in service either. I dont know about refunds though.

Comment: Actual service and luggage are not the only potential differences, often it's the change/cancellation fees and the quote does not say anything about that.

Comment: Even worse :( I asked them twice by phrasing the question differently. And the only answer they give is that there is no difference other than the discount percentage.